# UPnP Open port on local device?

Tags: network, ports

I ran Zenmap on a local IP address and found that it had one port running UPnP open and the guessed OS was a Windows distribution. Is this normal? Should I be concerned about it? In what ways could it be exploited if it is a risk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes an open UPnP-port is a potential vulnerability. There is a broad range on how to exploit the UPnP-protocol.Read this link for more information: [UPnP Networking Flaws Expose Tens Of Millions Of IPs To Hack Attacks
Read more at http://www.silicon.co.uk/workspace/upnp-attacks-over-networks-rapid7-security-105786#Wi3XEMHgsbw0VXKw.99](http://www.silicon.co.uk/workspace/upnp-attacks-over-networks-rapid7-security-105786)
If you don't need it to be open for some reason close it.